# Open PDF fails with "The requested file operation failed because the storage policy blocks that type of file."

Tags: security, pdf, windows-11, adobe-reader

I try to open a PDF document by double-click on the file, but it fails with this error:

> There was an error opening this document.  The requested file operation failed because the storage policy blocks that type of file.  For more information contact your system administrator.

[image]

It fails only when I try to open it with double-click from Explorer. I am using latest Windows 11.

- I can open the file from Acrobat Reader in File -> Open... Menu
- The PDF is stored in `d:\Temp\Nauders 3-Länder Enduro Bike 2023_web.pdf`. If I copy it to other location, e.g. "My Documents..." or any other location (I tried 2-3 different folders on my C:\ and D:\ drive), then it works fine
- I de-installed and Adobe Reader and installed again -> no change
- I have a HP computer. Some pages advice to remove HP Sure Click, but this is not installed. However, the computer has a bunch of other HP products installed:

  - HP Documentation
  - HP Notifications
  - HP Performance Advisor
  - HP Security Update Service
  - HP Sure Recover
  - HP Sure Run Module
  - HP Wolf Security
  - HP Wolf Security - Console

I tried to find the related Group Policy, but I was not able to find it.

Actually, I found a solution. I renamed folder `D:\Temp` to `Temp-old` and made a copy to `D:\Temp`, i.e. created new folder.

Now it works, but I don't think this is a proper solution. Security settings of these folders are the same.

Any idea to fix it in a decent way?

Meanwhile I found some more information:

HP Sure Click is bundled in HP Wolf Security.

When I open the file directly in Acrobat Reader, then the Acrobat Reader windows header shows

```
Nauders 3-Länder Enduro Bike 2023_web.pdf - HP Sure Secure View
```

[image]

and it is also shown in HP Wolf Security as isolated application:

[image]

So, looks like HP Wolf Security is the culprit. Unfortunately, you can hardly change any configuration in HP Wolf Security. I don't know yet, whether I should uninstall HP Wolf Security or not. It might be justified if it treats a PDF file as a security threat. However, if I move such a file to another folder and the threat is bypassed, then such protection is pointless.

Comment: Just FYI, "For starters" means "to begin with" or "the first thing to try". It does not mean that someone presumes YOU are a beginner at something.

Comment: It seems that Wolf Security is trying to protect from temporary locations, but doing so in an awkward way. If you already have updated and functional antivirus software and this is not a business computer, you should be fine uninstalling the over-zealous Wolf Security product.